# Source of most common SAP runtime error descriptions

Tags: runtime-error, sap-basis

I am searching the Web for some kind of table, that has a definition or description of the the most common SAP runtime errors. This if for the following reason:

I want to create a report about the weekly occurred short dumps in the SAP.
My colleagues do send me the data, and I want to add a short text for all dumps which occurred, so people can roughly understand what happened.

My plan was to use the "What happened?" Text from the TCODE ST22, but can I somehow get this text for all dumps, or just for the dumps which occurred and I therefore can access to see this text.

Searching the web does only provide answers how to solve those issues, but in most cases do not give a description.

I am quite new to SAP, therefore I cannot describe each dump from my own knowledge.

So my question:

Is there a source, which lists all, or at least quite a few ( 30-40) short dumps along with their description? (I know there are around 1900 different short dumps)

I have access to a SAP sandbox and the SAP marketplace, but I couldn't find anything so far...

If anything is unclear or information are missing, please add a comment and I will provide them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the texts in the database table `SNAPT`. There is a report named `RSLISTDUMPS` to display the texts. You can view the table contents using the transaction `SE16` or `SE16N`, and you can execute the report using the transaction `SA38`, which should be basic knowledge for anyone who is attempting to document short dumps...

Comment: If you could add a short description on how to execute this report (somehow with SA38? ), I will be happy to accept your answer

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, but I am fairly new to SAP and just do the presentation of the results... But in any way, this was very helpful.